# Why do partition managers need their own drivers?

Tags: windows, drivers, partitioning, disk-management

Why do so many partition management tools, like EASEUS Partition Master, Acronis Disk Director, etc. require their own drivers in order to run?

In other words, what do they need to do that cannot be accomplished without a dedicated driver?

Direct disk access is completely possible from user-mode in Windows, so I'm curious why these tools insist on installing a custom driver to do their work. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I just installed EaseUS PM Home Edition to take a peek... but I can't find any driver: nothing in the installed files, registry, or MS Info - what's the name of the driver file?

Comment: @ckhan: Interesting... at one point I thought I saw epm-something-something.sys, but that was when I was doing a partitioning operation. I don't see it now. Let me look and see if I can find anything...

Comment: @ckhan: Ah, I knew I wasn't going crazy. :-) It's `\Windows\System32\epmntdrv.sys`.

Comment: I should note that not every program does this. (I haven't seen Paragon do this, for example.) And, programs which *do* do this, do so to different degrees... for example EASEUS's is very weird, because it bypasses *everything* and writes directly to the disk, even any drivers that might be present directly on top of the disk driver (such as FancyCache). I/O from EASEUS won't show up as Disk I/O, but as "other" I/O.

Comment: As Mehrdad said, they are filter drivers so the program has exclusive disk access, which is needed when imaging or cloning the hard drive while in windows. Acronis does this also. Paragon  uses hotcore3.sys in some of its product installations.

Answer (score 3):

@David Schwartz has suggested it's because they're intercepting all disk access. That certainly sounds credible to me. But I'm wondering if that's the whole story. I've been poking around the EaseUS driver, `empmntdrv.sys`. A few things to note:

1. It's loaded as soon as I start the UI, not actually partitioning anything.
2. EaseUS forums have plenty of [posts of people complaining that no partitions show up](http://forum.easeus.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=18483&hilit=epmntdrv.sys) when they launch the UI, and the stock answer from EaseUS support is: re-install the driver. This makes me thing it's being used to actually read the table.
3. Brought out the big-guns: [PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/download-pe-explorer.htm) to disassemble the driver file. Mostly greek to me, of course, but a few things do jump out. First, the symbol table shows the list of system calls made to `ntoskrnel.exe`, and that include mucking with symbolic links:

   ```
   ; Imports from ntoskrnl.exe
       extrn DbgPrint
       extrn ExAllocatePoolWithTag
       extrn ExFreePoolWithTag
       extrn IoBuildAsynchronousFsdRequest
       extrn IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest
       extrn IoCreateDevice
       extrn IoCreateSymbolicLink
       extrn IoDeleteDevice
       extrn IoDeleteSymbolicLink
       extrn IoFreeIrp
       extrn IoFreeMdl
       extrn IoGetAttachedDeviceReference
       extrn IoGetDeviceObjectPointer
       extrn IofCallDriver
       extrn IofCompleteRequest
       extrn KeBugCheckEx
       extrn KeInitializeEvent
       extrn KeSetEvent
       extrn KeTickCount
       extrn KeWaitForSingleObject
       extrn MmMapLockedPagesSpecifyCache
       extrn MmUnlockPages
       extrn ObfDereferenceObject
       extrn ObfReferenceObject
       extrn RtlAnsiCharToUnicodeChar
       extrn RtlInitUnicodeString
       extrn RtlUnicodeStringToInteger
       extrn memcpy
       extrn memset
   ```

   Note also that these are not the filter driver routines, they're low-level IO ones.
   (Not `FltGetDiskDeviceObject`, rather `IoGetDeviceObjectPointer`.
4. Even more snooping around found a few constants that might give more clues. Like most Windows compiled code, there's a hard ref to the PDB file, usually with the path on the computer that created it:

   h:\epm2.0\01_projectarea\00_source\epm2\mod.windiskaccessdriver\windiskaccessdriver\objfre_wxp_x86\i386\epmntdrv.pdb

   That's probably the developer's actually project name: "win disk access driver"
   I think they need the driver to actually read the table in a way that's useful to them.
5. Then there's this constant, which really looks interesting:

   ```
   \Device\Harddisk%u\Partition0
   ```

   That looked interesting enough that I tracked where it was referenced in the 
   disassembled code, which took me here:

   ```
    0001051E  68C6190100                       push    L000119C6
    00010523  6A78                             push    00000078h
    00010525  50                               push    eax
    00010526  E85BFFFFFF                       call    SUB_L00010486
    0001052B  83C420                           add esp,00000020h
    0001052E  85C0                             test    eax,eax
    00010530  7404                             jz  L00010536
    00010532                           L00010532:
    00010532  33C0                             xor eax,eax
    00010534  EB43                             jmp L00010579
    00010536                           L00010536:
    00010536  8D4584                           lea eax,[ebp-7Ch]
    00010539  50                               push    eax
    0001053A  8D8574FFFFFF                     lea eax,[ebp-0000008Ch]
    00010540  50                               push    eax
    00010541  FF15941A0100                     call    [ntoskrnl.exe!RtlInitUnicodeString]
    00010547  8D4580                           lea eax,[ebp-80h]
    0001054A  50                               push    eax
    0001054B  8D857CFFFFFF                     lea eax,[ebp-00000084h]
    00010551  50                               push    eax
    00010552  56                               push    esi
    00010553  8D8574FFFFFF                     lea eax,[ebp-0000008Ch]
    00010559  50                               push    eax
    0001055A  FF15901A0100                     call    [ntoskrnl.exe!IoGetDeviceObjectPointer]
   ```
6. So what magic thing does [`IoGetDeviceObjectPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549198(v=vs.85).aspx), which is only available in
   kernel mode, tell you when you call it on `\Device\Harddisk0\Partition0` ?

   From an [ancient post to comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.nt.kernel-mode](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.nt.kernel-mode/browse_thread/thread/2d4ddde047b69f38/9285760ea185499a%3Fq%3D%2522Stan%2BMiller%2522%239285760ea185499a&ei=iGwTS6eaOpW8Qpmqic0O&sa=t&ct=res&cd=4&source=groups&usg=AFQjCNFjJ8jhd4pTtLvlkEPiKGWh9hpFcQ?pli=1):

   > If you get the pointer to \device\harddisk(n)\partition(n) using 
   >   IoGetDeviceObjectPointer(), you will get a pointer to the partitions device 
   >   object. If you want the physical disk device object, you need to get the 
   >   pointer to \device\harddisk(n)\partition0.

   So partition0 lets us get to the [physical disk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804035.aspx)

   And that gives us a lot of performance metrics and counters that
   are below the logical level for the disk.
7. Finally, trying to find a time that I thought it might actually be using the driver.
   I ran a "surface test" from EaseUS, and I see stats on the performance.
   They could be doing that from user level, but in Process Explorer, when I took
   a snapshot, I suddenly saw the `Device.mo` dll active: presumably the part of the system
   that talks to the driver.

Still not sure if that's a good answer to the question.
But it was fun exploring, anyway! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Indeed, there *are* functions available in kernel mode which are not available in user mode as functions (take `IoCreateDisk` for instance), but there *are* (semi-?)equivalents to many of them (e.g. [`IOCTL_DISK_CREATE_DISK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365155.aspx), or the user-mode perf counters, etc.). The fact that some programs don't seem to need a kernel driver (or at least not nearly as much) makes me wonder why other programs do. But +1, this is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

They need to intercept all disk accesses. For example, suppose you're in the process of cloning a partition. If any writes are made to the disk during the cloning process, the sector written to must be cloned prior to permitting the write to go through, otherwise the resulting clone will be inconsistent.

Comment: Doesn't Windows already have volume snapshots/shadow copies precisely for this purpose? (E.g. [this functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548334.aspx).) After all, programs like [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415) certainly don't seem to need this, and yet they certainly need to block writes...

Comment: Disk2VHD doesn't try to change a partition while Windows is using it like partition managers do. Disk2VHD doesn't try to present a virtual partition to Windows during its operations.

Comment: It still has to block writes though, doesn't it?

Comment: Also, *no program* (or at least, no sane program...) changes a partition while Windows is using it. (This is *enforced* in Windows Vista/7, but it's true in every version past XP.) Furthermore, *no [sane] partition manager* tries to present a virtual partition to Windows while it proceeds with changing a partition. Partition managers just lock the partition when they can, and reboot into native mode when they can't.

Comment: That is not true. Acronis Backup and Restore, for example, can boot from a partition while it's restoring it.

Comment: First of all, Acronis Backup and Restore is not a partition manager. Second of all, what exactly do you mean by "restore" here? Is it a file-based or an image-based restoration?

Comment: It has various capabilities that fall into various categories. It combined features from both Disk Director and TrueImage. But that's really neither here nor there. The feature sets are overlapping and there's no clear line between the two. The same functionality could involve moving a partition from one disk to another. And the major point is that partition managers in fact have drivers precisely so they can do this kind of thing. (In many product lines, all the products use the same drivers.)

Comment: What you say doesn't make sense: you can't restore a partition and boot Windows from it at the same time... heck, your program is running *on* Windows, so if Windows isn't running, who's running you?? Unless, of course, you mean a *file-based* restoration (instead of an image-based one), when Windows has already booted, in which case, I don't understand what's so special about that... why can't you just copy normally onto the disk, or (if you really need to do something weird) use the Volume Snapshot feature built into Windows (which I already linked to)? Why a separate driver?

Comment: @Mehrdad: You can restore a partition and boot Windows from it at the same time. Acronis Backup and Restore does this. It interposes its driver between the kernel and the disk. On each sector access, the driver checks if the sector has been restored yet. If not, it delays the read, restores that sector, and then permits the read to occur. It has to restore enough to load the kernel and its own driver before and during the boot process. (I think you drastically underestimate how sophisticated modern disk management programs are.)

Comment: No, I'm most certainly *not* underestimating them. (What *would* have surprised me is if you had said the kernel didn't need to be running, since then it'd be an entire OS.) The key point I'm trying to make is what you finally said: *"It has to restore enough to load the kernel and its own driver before and during the boot process."* So that means Windows has to be running before it can run, right? Which *still* begs -- but doesn't answer -- my question: Doesn't the existing volume snapshot or VSS functionality in Windows already let you do this? (This is the third time I've asked this...)

Comment: No. The VSS functionality is for consistent reading of files only. It doesn't give you a consistent volume snapshot (which usually doesn't matter) and it doesn't let you intercept writes.

Comment: Oooooh, so you mean VSS is for freezing the view of the drive for the *program*, but their driver is for freezing the view for the *rest* of the OS? That's interesting!...

Comment: Yes. There are a lot of things you can't do with VSS. You cannot affect what the OS sees. You cannot intercept writes. All VSS gives you is a snapshot of files that you can read. It's good for file backup and not that much else.

Comment: That's very interesting! I'm not sure if this is precisely the reason for this question (since the partition managers I've seen work offline anyway), but it brings up a very important (and I think somewhat subtle) point I missed, thanks! +1